# shift; shift versus shift 2 when using bash

Tags: bash

Have encountered some statements that `shift; shift` is better than
`shift 2` when using bash, but I need some convincing explanation.  What happens with `shift; shift` and how does it handle things better in case of problems with how positional arguments are passed?

Answer (score 7):

`shift 2` fails if there's only one positional parameter, and it *leaves* that parameter there:

```
$ set -- abc
$ shift; shift
$ echo "exit status $? args left $# first arg expands to '$1'"
exit status 1 args left 0 first arg expands to ''

$ set -- abc
$ shift 2
$ echo "exit status $? args left $# first arg expands to '$1'"
exit status 1 args left 1 first arg expands to 'abc'
```

Both show exit status 1, since the latest `shift` fails in both cases. It's just that in the first case, the first `shift` already cleared the lone positional parameter.

That was with Bash. In some shells, trying to shift more positional parameters than there are even causes the shell to exit with an error:

```
$ dash -c 'set -- abc; shift 2; echo end'
dash: 1: shift: can't shift that many
```

This could come up in an argument parsing loop, e.g. if you have

```
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    # ...
    if [ "$1" = -f ]; then
        file=$2
        shift 2;
    fi
done`
```

then giving `-f` with no argument after would leave Bash in an endless loop. With a double `shift` it'd just set `file` to the empty string, which might give a more meaningful error later (e.g. "file not found"). Of course one would more properly do it by checking if `$2` is set, or by using `getopt`, but anyway.

Comment: I meant `shift N` with N > $#

Comment: I am thinking hard on the explanation.  Fundamentally,  `shift 2` fails if there is only one positional arguments.  When it fails, the positional is not shifted at all.  Whereas the command `shift; shift` passes the first `shift` command (and the positional parameter in moved by one), but the second `shift` fails without doing anything on the positional parameters.  This means that when the shift command fails, it keeps the positional parameters intact.

Comment: @Dilna, yes. Could come up in an argument parsing loop, see edit

Comment: That's where I use them, and where this detail cropped up.  Felicitations @ilkkachu

Comment: Note that bash's `shift` does give an error when in POSIX mode. See also `shift "$(( 2 - ($# < 2) - ($# < 1) ))"` to shift by up to 2 elements (or less if there are fewer). Or in `zsh`: `argv[1,2]=()`

Answer (score 5):

In the case where there are two or more positional parameters, there is no difference between `shift 2` and `shift` twice.

In the case where there is only one positional parameter, `shift 2` would not shift that value off the list, and would exit with a non-zero exit-status.  On the other hand, running `shift` twice would obviously remove the value from the list with the first `shift`.  The second `shift` would still terminate with a non-zero exit-status.